# Difference between onChangeText={setAnswer} and onChangeText={(text) => setAnswer(text)}?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to application development. Both onChangeText below works fine. Is there any difference between these two? Is it a problem if I use onChangeText={setAnswer} ?

```js
const Page = (props) => {

    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("")

    return (
        <TextInput
            //onChangeText={(text) => setAnswer(text)}
            onChangeText={setAnswer}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in this specific situation, because the onChangeText prop will pass an argument to the function (in here: setAnswer) and change state;
But if you want to pass a function which takes an argument outside the textInput scope (consider passing second state to the function), you'll need to pass an arrow function to onChangeText prop.
I hope I explained it well enough..